# How do i convert a json array object of an object into a java 8 optional list of that object

Tags: java, json, option-type

```java
   public Optional<GetCategoryResponseDto> GetCategory(AppUser foundUser) throws Exception {

        Optional<GetCategoryResponseDto> optional;
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        org.json.simple.JSONObject json;
        //fix for lazy user details not loaded
        if (foundUser.getAppUserDetail() == null) {
            foundUser = appUserService.findByID(foundUser.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new ModelNotFoundException("Invalid user"));
        }
        LOGGER.debug("foundUser {} ", gson.toJson(foundUser.getAppUserDetail().getPhoneNumber()));

        String output = getCategoryServiceController.myGetCategory();
        LOGGER.debug("output {} ", output);
        json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(output);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        GetCategoryResponseDto dto = new GetCategoryResponseDto();
        dto = mapper.readValue((DataInput) json, GetCategoryResponseDto.class);
        return Optional.of(dto);
```

Thats the updated code and still this line "        GetCategoryResponseDto dto = mapper.readValue(json, GetCategoryResponseDto.class);" is still causing syntax errors

Comment: `Optional<GetCategoryResponseDto> optional = null;` Never do this. A variable of type Optional should never be null.

Comment: ok got that, but how do I get the desired result

Comment: *I am expecting output in the form of an optional list of my custom `GetCategoryResponseDto` objects*... Don't wrap collections within `Optional` either. By the way, the signature of the method differs from what your requirement is. So not really clear what you're looking for and from where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If below line returns JSON formatted string then you don't need any `JSONParser`

```
String output = getCategoryServiceController.myGetCategory();
```

[ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) has `readValue` method that takes `String` and `Class<T>` as arguments

```
public <T> T readValue(String content,
          Class<T> valueType)
        throws IOException,
               JsonParseException,
               JsonMappingException
```

You can just use that method

```
String output = getCategoryServiceController.myGetCategory();
LOGGER.debug("output {} ", output

GetCategoryResponseDto dto = mapper.readValue(json, GetCategoryResponseDto.class

return Optional.of(dto);
```

**Note** There are lot more unnecessary lines in `GetCategory`, for example

```
Optional<GetCategoryResponseDto> optional;
org.json.simple.JSONObject json = null;
```

And also i see `mapper` is null, you might face `NullPointerException` if it is null

Comment: GetCategoryResponseDto dto = mapper.readValue(json, GetCategoryResponseDto.class);
is still giving me syntax errors, I need help guys. this line is preventing my program from running

Comment: What is the error message? It might throw compile time error you should handle them @MIikeEps

Comment: I update the code again and see the error, at least this time it runs but I still get a run time error>> "org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.io.DataInput"

Comment: i don't know why you are casting `(DataInput) json`? @MIikeEps

Comment: Thanks so much Deadpool, It's working now i used "        dto = mapper.readValue(output, GetCategoryResponseDto.class);
"  @Deadpool you are the best

Comment: @downvoter at least you should have explained for down vote?